# get azure service status from all region in json format

Tags: azure

I am working on a automation where i need to fetch the service status from specific region and show that in splunk as bar/line chart. Is there any way we can get the details from https://azure.status.microsoft/en-us/status as json data. I searched google and could not find anything related. Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resourcehealth/

Comment: @PeterBons This API is limited to resources and does not provide information regarding `specific region`

Comment: I don't see an API to fetch region specific status. But, I see something with subscription. I hope you monitor regions where your subscription is active rather blindly monitoring regions (has indeed no value). If this is the case, you can use `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses?api-version=2018-07-01` & fetch `value[0].properties.availabilityState` to know the status of one of the resources in each region by iterating through `location` property. I know this isn't what you are looking for, but close.